# PySide2 - How to use a custom widget from import?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to define a custom control to import it to my main window, but when I do it, the control does not have the settings applied that I defined in the class.

This is the basic implementation:

A basic main script to start the app.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

from mainwindow import MainWindow

if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
       app = QApplication(sys.argv)
       mainWindow = MainWindow()
       mainWindow.show()
       app.exec_()
       sys.exit(0)
   except NameError:
       print("Name error: ", sys.exc_info()[1])
   except SystemExit:
       print("Closing process...")
   except Exception:
       print(sys.exc_info()[1])
```

The mainwindow class:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

from widget import Widget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGui()


    def setGui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Widget Test")
        geometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry(self)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, geometry.width() * 0.3, geometry.height() * 0.3)

        widget = Widget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

And the control:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QTextEdit

class Widget(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setWidget()

    def setWidget(self):
        editor = QTextEdit()
        editor.setFont('Courier')
        editor.setFontPointSize(12)
        editor.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit "
                           "{padding-left:10; padding-top:30;padding-bottom:10; padding-right:10; "
                           "background:red;}")
```

The output is this:

As you see the background of the control is white instead red as is defined at the class

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have applied the stylesheet to another widget that is also a QTextEdit but is a local variable. You have to apply the changes to the same class:

```py
class Widget(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setFont("Courier")
        self.setFontPointSize(12)
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "QTextEdit "
            "{padding-left:10; padding-top:30;padding-bottom:10; padding-right:10; "
            "background:red;}"
        )
```